# How to run a gRPC Server and an Express Server on the Same PORT in cloud run

Tags: node.js, express, grpc, google-cloud-run

Are there any known techniques or hacks for running both an Express Server and a GRPC Server on the same port? I am aware Cloud Run exposes just a single Port for a service instance.

So, I'm literally just looking for hacks as it stands now.

Like below

```
const app = express();

const port=process.env.PORT; 

app.listen(port,()=>{});

gRPCServer.bindAsync(`0.0.0.0:${port}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => {
      gRPCServer.start();
});
```

I wish to expose some routes to my users via express and only use GRPC for internal micro services communication.

I saw https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway but there are very few documentations on how to use it with NodeJS plus I **DON'T** want to generate client libraries. I prefer dynamic code generation.

Comment: Not a full answer, but should be enough to get you started: use nginx as frontend reverse proxy (as [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run)) to route requests to the 2 upstreams - [For GRPC](https://medium.com/nirman-tech-blog/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-grpc-820d35642bff) and [for node + express](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-run-a-node-js-server-with-nginx/) . Use seperate URL paths to differentiate requests to the different upstreams.

Comment: You can perform multiplexing in Go, but I don't know in Node.